# How do I make a selection from a text file based on what text is inside it (Python)

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my file.
I've split it so each line is a separate list eg.

```
myList = [['Adam','16','Yes'], ['Fred','22','No']]
```

and trying to make a variable that only select lines with contain a "Yes".

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to select only lists whose third member is equal to `"Yes"`:

```
selected = [data for data in your_list if data[2] == "Yes"]
```

Comment: @KedarKodgire, `data` is a sublist of `myList` in the question, and `data[2]` is the 3rd element of `data` because lists' indexes start at zero, so that `data[0]` is the first element.

Comment: This seems to just return "[]".

Comment: @NovInf, it doesn't if I try it with `myList` in your question.

Comment: Hmm. It may be due to the fact that I'm importing the file using: with open('New Text Document.txt') as f:
    myList = f.read().splitlines() - and the text file is those three separated by lines, rather than just defining a list.

Comment: @NovInf, `splitlines` gives you a list of strings. Now you need to split each of them to get a representation like the one in your question: `myList = [line.split() for line in f]` or, which looks more complex and redundant to me, `myList = [line.split() for line in f.read().splitlines()]`.

Answer (score 0):

myList = your_input_sequence

lambda function to select only matching text: `lambda x: x[<position_of_string_to_compare>].lower()`

Desired function:

> result = filter(lambda x: x[2].lower() == 'yes', myList)

```
>>> myList
[['Adam', '16', 'Yes'], ['Fred', '22', 'No']]
>>> res = filter(lambda x: x[2].lower()=='yes', myList)
>>> res
[['Adam', '16', 'Yes']]
```

Comment: `x[2].lower()` not `x[2].islower()` as the latter returns a Boolean.

Comment: This returns <filter object at 0x02DA6470> for me =(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
myList = [['Adam','16','Yes'], ['Fred','22','No']]
x='Yes'
list1=[]
for i in myList:
    for j in i:       
        if x==j:
            list1.append(i)
for x in list1:
    a=" ".join(x)
f= open("textDocument.txt","w+")
f.write(a)
c=f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: This works well. How would I adapt this so that it imports a text file rather than defining a list? I've been using: with open('New Text Document.txt') as f:
    myList = f.read().splitlines() - but it doesnt work.

Comment: So basically you want to store the final answer in the .txt file,is it?